# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'method'

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, authentication, flask

I have a web srv, and this is how i do my login

```
@app.route('/do_login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def do_login():
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']
```

So, when i run the app and i try to login i receive the error "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'method'"

This is also my html page

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="{{ url_for('do_login') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="exmple@ex.it">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="*****">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
            <a class = "nav-link" href="/registrazione">Registrati</a> 
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your indentation is off. Aside from that, have you defined something called `request` in the global scope?

Comment: Indentation is just a copy-paste error, in the code is right, request is an import from the flask library

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have the line `from flask import request` in the file
2. Make sure you did not redefine `request` anyway. Either you have explicitly defined another function called `request`

   ```
    def request():
        ...
   ```

   or you have assigned a function to `request`

   ```
     request = some_random_method
   ```

Comment: I had a func request, in the bottom of the file, thanks i didn't notice that